# tableview constraints to optimal window width

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and have trouble with constraints in my NSTableView.

I have this tableview:

[image]

You can see, that my textfields not use the complete width of my tableview. I would like to fill the complete width with my textfields, but only the red textfield should get a larger width like this:

[image]

But it doesn't work yet :(
Example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PBtMQt9GdORE1xSUUxeVFaWVU

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are those things table view columns, or do you just have a single column with a bunch of text fields in a row? (And please, don't post links to code. No one wants to click a link and download your project. Post _code_. Thanks.)

Comment: it is only one single column

Comment: So do you know about NSStackView? It does _exactly_ what you're describing (though this has nothing whatever to do with table views.)

Comment: not yet - can this solves my problem?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't know anything about auto layout constraints you have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing an NSStackView. It's a view that distributes its arranged subviews for you, in accordance with your configuration. You want a Fill configuration where the red text field has a lower content hugging priority than the other fields, so that it alone can stretch.